# Mapping many to many relationship in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I'm try make a test in EF, creating a many to many relationship, because I always mapping One to One or One to Many, I has get a example in the internet for try, the example is working for insert registers, but I can't read registers

Here is my classes, I don't know what is `HashSet`, I get this code in the site

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Course> CoursesAttending { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        CoursesAttending = new HashSet<Course>();
    }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Students { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        Students = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
}
```

Here is my Context

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    public SchoolContext()
        : base("MyDb")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().
            HasMany(c => c.Students).
            WithMany(p => p.CoursesAttending).
            Map(
                m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("CourseId");
                    m.MapRightKey("PersonId");
                    m.ToTable("PersonCourses");
                });

    }
}
```

When I insert registers is right

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
    {
        Course math = new Course();
        Course history = new Course();
        Course biology = new Course();
        math.Title = "Math";
        history.Title = "History";
        biology.Title = "Biology";

        db.Courses.Add(math);
        db.Courses.Add(history);
        db.Courses.Add(biology);

        Person john = new Person();
        john.FirstName = "John";
        john.LastName = "Paul";
        john.CoursesAttending.Add(history);
        john.CoursesAttending.Add(biology);

        db.People.Add(john);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But when I try select register for show content, is not work, it just print nothing

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
    {
        Pearson p = db.Peasons.First();
        Console.WriteLine(p.CoursesAttending.First().Title);
    }
}
```

I had check in the database, registers exist, what is the problem?

Please teach me how to make select in many to many relationship with code first.

Comment: If you use `.Add()` on navigation properties in a many-to-many relationship, does EF automatically update a corresponding joint table?

Comment: @Celdor EF does update the corresponding join table ofcourse.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First off, you may want to enable lazy loading by making the collections *virtual*:

```
public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesAttending { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Person> Students { get; set; }
```

This allows EF to create derived classes (*proxies*) from `Course` and `Person` that override the collections with logic to load their data from the data store.

When you do that you will see that

```
Console.WriteLine(p.CoursesAttending.First().Title);
```

will execute a separate query to populate `CoursesAttending`.

Alternatively, or additionally, you may decide to prevent round trips to the database by *eager loading* like so:

```
Person p = db.Persons.Include(p => p.CoursesAttending).First();
```

Which loads the `Person` *and* the `CoursesAttending` in one shot.

Comment: Great! it is work!! So... why Include is using for fast select? I don't understand how to use Include

Comment: As the word says, `Include` includes properties into the query. Usually it is more efficient to have one SQL query (with joins) than getting objects and querying their associated objects later in separate queries.

Answer (score -1):

Remove your class constructor and that OnModelCreating method.
EF handles Many to Many relationship. You don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: Using data annotations can by default give you a funky naming convention and by providing the fluent api code, this unwanted naming can be avoided.

Comment: This answer is IMO OT and not helpful at all.